# create hyperlink with unique id while iterating a model in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

```
<%var i=1;%>
<%foreach (var commentitem in item.commentsModelList)
   { 
    <table border="0"  class="commentbox">
     <tr>
        <td>
           <%: Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => commentitem.CommentClob)%>
        </td>

     </tr>
     <tr>
        <%var rid = "reply" + i;%>
        <td>  <input id="<%:rid %>" type="button" value="reply"/>
     </td>
       <td>

      <%--addded--%>
        <div id="<%:rboxid %>">
            <input id="Text1" type="text" />
            <input id="postreply" type="button" value="postreply" />

        </div>
    </td>

     </tr>
  </table>
<% i++;}%>
```

I have the following query

1.
I  want to display alert boxes when different hyperlink with different reply id is clicked.

**Edited**

2.
i want a to hide these div on page load and show div with id replybox1 when link with id reply1 is clicked and same for other divs

3.Is there any way to create div dymaically and performing the same functionality

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get an alert of the id when clicking on the input button, you can use this script. ( Assuming you have jQuery available in your page)

```
   $(function(){
      $(".commentbox input[type='button']").click(function(){
        var id=$(this).attr("id");
        alert(id);
      });
    });
```

As Hasan already mentioned. you should probably use the `comentItemId` instead of using the `i` variable

**EDIT**  As per the update in question, This script will hide all divs in the page load and show only those div with id `replybox1` when input with `reply1` being clicked.

```
   $(function(){
      $(".commentbox div").hide();
      $(".commentbox input[type='button']").click(function(){
        var id=$(this).attr("id");
        var replyBoxId=id.substring(5);
        $("#replybox"+replyBoxId).show();
      });
    });
```

Comment: yes its working but i have another query i have edited my question please have a look

Comment: yes it is working but is there any way if i can div dyamically and then do this functionlity

Comment: @prerna: What you mean by that ? I guess, you should better post another question specific to that with relevant code for that

Comment: i have posted new quesition on the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10163305/create-div-dynamically-on-click-of-a-hyperlink-in-asp-net-mvc

Answer (score 1):

Use `modelItem.Id` for disambiguating links instead of for loop counter;

```
     <tr>
        <%var rid = "reply" + modelItem.Id ;%>
        <td>  <input id="<%:rid %>" type="button" value="reply"/>
     </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have defined the variable `i` *inside* the `for` loop. This means you are allocating a new integer with value 1 for each iteration.

Try moving the definition of `i` outside of the loop.

Comment: yes i have done it .....thks can u help me how to display alertbox when a particular hyperlink with particular id is clicked