# appending div to a div in jquery

Tags: jquery

```
$(function() {
    $(".commentbox .btnReply").click(function() {
        $(this).hide();
        var id = $(this).attr("id").split("-")[1]
        var strDiv = "<input type='text' class='txtCmnt' id='txtReply-" + id + "' /> <input type='button' class='btnSave' value='Save' id='btnSave-" + id + "' /> ";
        $("#container-" + id).html(strDiv);
    });
    var i = 1;
    $(".commentbox").on("click", ".btnSave", function() {
        var itemId = $(this).attr("id").split("-")[1]
        var txt = $(this).parent().find(".txtCmnt").val();
        var divid = itemId + "-" + i;

 i++;
            alert("i" + i);
        alert("replypostid" + divid);

        $.post("Handler/Topic.ashx", {
            reply: txt,
            id: itemId
        }, function(data) {
            alert(data);
            var str = "<div id='replytopost" + divid + "'></div>";
            $("#replytopost" + divid).append(data);

            $("#container-" + itemId).append(str);


        })

    });
});
```

I want to append data returned from post function to a dynamically created div which is appended to another div.

The jsfiddle link is
http://jsfiddle.net/UGMkq/49/

alert(data) is printing correct output but div with data is not getting appended .

**Edited**

If I click first save button it is giving replypostid1-1 and then
 when I click second button alert is giving **replypostid2-2** instead I want **replypostid2-1**

http://jsfiddle.net/UGMkq/50/

Comment: whats the full url of Handler/Topic.ashx?

I can't test on jsfiddle because $.post isn't executing from there

Comment: It looks like you haven't added the `div` you trying to select to the DOM yet. You need to either append the `div` to the DOM or append the `data` to the `str` variable i.e. $(str).append(data);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are creating a string, then trying to append to it as if it existed in the DOM.  Instead, try this:

```
$("#container-" + itemId).append(
   $('<div/>')
      .attr('id', '#replytopost'+divid)
      .append( data )
);
```

**edit**

I don't think relying on keeping a counter in Javascript to handle the reply count is a good solution.  If the page is refreshed, that counter is lost/reset.

If this app is database driven, you should be able to get a count of current replies from the database and have better data consistency - have that passed back with the ajax call - maybe as a json object.  This will allow you to avoid keeping and incrementing that counter in JS.

```
$.post("Handler/Topic.ashx", { reply: txt, id: itemId }, function(data) {
   //Assuming a json object like { "id": 1, "text": "What ever data equals now" }
   var reply = JSON.parse( data );
   $("#container-" + itemId).append(
      $('<div/>')
         .attr('id', '#replytopost'+itemId+'_'+reply.id)
         .append( reply.text )
   );
});
```

Comment: I have updated me my question please have a look at it.thks the code you have given works

Comment: @prerna - edited answer for you.  I believe you may have better luck modifying your approach.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling .append(data) on an element that does not exist yet; it's just something in a string.

I don't think that is a good way to create a new element either.  You should use `document.createElement()` and `element.appendChild()` or some jquery technique.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**: Try this code:

```
    $(".btnReply").on("click", function() {
    thisvar = $(this).parent()
input = $("<input>")
input.appendTo(thisvar)
$("<br>").appendTo(thisvar)
$("<input>")
.attr("type", "submit")
.appendTo(thisvar)
        .on("click", function() {
        //Handle POST stuff here
        val = input.val()
        $("<div>").addClass("txtCmnt").text(val).appendTo(thisvar)
        })
})​
```

The problem is

```
var str = "<div id='replytopost"+ divid + "'></div>";
       $("#replytopost" + divid).append(data);
```

When you create this div element, it does not automatically get appended to the DOM.
So when you are trying to fetch the div:

```
$("#replytopost" + divid)
```

it will fail. Here is how you do it:

```
// Create a div
    var str = $("<div>").attr("id", "replytopost"+divid)
//Access it
    str.append(data)
//Append it to anything
str.appendTo("body")
```

You have more than one errors of this kind. If you fix them all, it should work.

Comment: str.appendTo("#container-" + itemId); is giving error :- Object doesn't support this property or method

Comment: I rewrote your code (without the $.post stuff) . It is above. Try it here: http://jsfiddle.net/frp3z/

Comment: ok it works but I have updated my question pls have a look at it

Comment: I am trying to create functionality like this website where topic can have answers and each answer can have comments

Comment: Based on the input we gave you, you should be able to to this. Just repeat the same thing and try it out. You should do some tries by yourself and only when you are failing, you can post a question on this site.

Answer (score 0):

You switch the following before each other. You can't append on an element that doesn't exist.

```
var str = "<div id='replytopost"+ divid + "'></div>";
$("#container-" + itemId).append(str); // this has to be added first
$("#replytopost" + divid).append(data);
```